# Download large firebase database in parts and put it back together

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I normally use `firebase data:get` to retrieve data from my database. However, my database has grown too large for this at this time and I am getting the error: `The data requested exceeds the maximum size that can be accessed with a single request`.

I can typically use the `--shallow` tag, but in this case, I need the full node. Now that this node has grown to this size, I can try to denormalize it, but what is the best practice for downloading this data in parts and then stitching it back together in the mean time?

I'm guessing it'll involve these tags, do I just need to use guess and check to figure out where to start and end as I work my way through the list and are these commands (`start-at` and `end-at`) 0-indexed?

```
--limit-to-first <num>   limit to the first <num> results
--limit-to-last <num>    limit to the last <num> results
--start-at <val>         start results at <val> (based on specified ordering)
--end-at <val>           end results at <val> (based on specified ordering)
```

Comment: Could be useful: https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebak. Read more about it here: http://alexklibisz.roughdraft.io/3247dcba8c8d7936a0ce-creating-an-effective-firebase-backup-solution

Comment: Thanks @puf, I'm doing a download and conversion to csv, so these aren't exactly what I'm looking for. So if I create my own, I'm trying to run `firebase data:get --order-by-key --limit-to-first 1 /location/{location key}/guests -f my-app > info.json` and it's still telling me it is too large (although the guest is only 10 or so lines in json form), do you know what might be causing that?

Comment: I tried it with a smaller node, and this request with `--limit-to-first 100` worked just fine (even though it's the same size as far as json). Does it need to download the entire database before it can limit? I guess it's confusing that I can't pull even the first few without being over the limit. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: None of your queries are shallow, which means that they're more likely to hit limits. Firebak does a shallow load of the keys followed by then loading the nodes themselves in chunks. I'd recommend trying it. Even if you need to post-process the data or modify the code, their approach is most likely to succeed.